# How can I launch a systemd service at startup before another systemd service starts?

Tags: scripts, startup, systemd, automount

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an old HP Laptop

I've installed some software on it to create a small homemade plex server. I've installed sonarr, radarr, deluge, jackett, etc etc and they all automatically launch at startup!

A couple of days ago I decided to install rclone too and I've created (thanks to a GitHub project) a couple of folders that have to be mounted at each startup by launching a script (I launch it via terminal writing `sudo ~/bin/check.mount`). Sonarr and Radarr are set up to download stuff via deluge to a temp folder and then export it to one of these two mounted folders.

The problem is, by the time I manually launch the script Sonarr/Radarr are already up and running and can't find their root folders, so they give me an error.

What I'd like to do is create a mountgdrive.service (service, or whatever is necessary) to automatically launch the check.mount script and, if that's not enough, insert a delay in sonarr.service and radarr.service! Is that possible?

I wrote this with `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mountgdrive.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MountSmokeScreen
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/samsepioldoloresh4ze/bin/check.mount
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and added to sonarr.service and radarr.service `mountgdrive.service` in the `After=` bit, like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Sonarr
After=syslog.target network.target mountgdrive.service

[Service]
User=samsepioldoresh4ze
etcetc
....
```

But it's not working! Sonarr and Radarr start normally, but the drives are not mounted! What am I doing wrong?

---

Also, rtcwake doesn't work on my laptop - I think it's a kernel issue?! Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `sonarr.service` and `radarr.service` to be run after `mountgdrive.service` is up and running?

Comment: @Dan exactly! the problem is, the way I wrote it apparently `mountgdrive.service` runs but does nothing (it doesn't mount the drives), and then `sonarr.service` and `radarr.service` run normally because ubuntu executed `mountgdrive.service`

Comment: I would also recommend you look into [`.mount` units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html). If all your `mountgdrive.service` is doing is mounting a directory or similar, you may be able to change it to a `.mount` service. As it makes it more reliable specially since you have dependencies on it.

Answer (score 45):

The reason you are having this problem is because you are using `After=` while you also need `Requires=` or `Wants=`.

There are 3 main properties for managing dependencies. I'll try to briefly explain the difference but you can find more details at [[Unit] Section Options | freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BUnit%5D%20Section%20Options)

1. `After=`

   This option only sets the order of the units, it doesn't guarantee that the service has finished starting up.
2. `Wants=`

   This option allows your unit to start only after another unit has finished starting up. (Doesn't matter if it started successfully or not)
3. `Requires=`

   Just like `Wants=`, however, this will make your unit start only after the dependencies have successfully started.

You can also use [the inverse](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Mapping%20of%20unit%20properties%20to%20their%20inverses) of each of those options.

1. `After=` is inversed by `Before=`
2. `Wants=` is inversed by `WantedBy=`
3. `Requires=` is inversed by `RequiredBy=`

To fix your problem, you need to change your mount service to:

```
[Unit]
Description=MountSmokeScreen
After=network.target
Before=sonarr.service radarr.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/samsepioldoloresh4ze/bin/check.mount
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target sonarr.service radarr.service
```

Or you can add `Wants=mountgdrive.service` to the `sonarr.service` and `radarr.service` units.

You can do that without modifying the default files by running the following (You need to do the same for `radarr.service`):

```
systemctl edit sonarr.service
```

And insert the following:

```
[Unit]
Wants=mountgdrive.service
```

Note: You can replace `Wants=` with `Requires` or `WantedBy=` with `RequiredBy=` if you don't want the two services to start at all if `mountgdrive.service` fails (Though `Wants=` is usually enough and even recommended in the docs).

EDIT: The `WantedBy` and `RequiredBy` options can only be used under the `[Install]` section. (Thanks [@Yankee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024916/how-can-i-launch-a-systemd-service-at-startup-before-another-systemd-service-sta/1024921#comment1948223_1024921))

Comment: thanks for `Wants=` and `WantedBy=`, I'll definitely used them!! I get this error though when I restart the laptop https://i.imgur.com/a3LE3G9.png

Comment: There seems to be an error in the script. You can see it from the line ending with `Can't open /.config/SmokeScreen/smokescreen.conf`. Maybe you have "~/.config/..." in yoru script. You should replace the tilde (`~`) with the full path i.e. `/home/you_user_name/.config/....` (Or use relative paths to your script)

Comment: https://github.com/FourFingerLifeHug/SmokeScreen/blob/master/check.mount - this is the check.mount script, so I should change all the $(HOME) and $(bindir) with the full paths? Thanks!

Comment: @samsepioldoloresh4ze Yep, `$HOME` isn't available at boot time, because there isn't a logged in user yet.

Comment: Should `WantedBy=` be in the `[Unit]` section? I thought it can only go in `[Install]`.

Comment: I dont think it can go under `[Unit]`. Whenever I add a `WantedBy=` clause under the `[Unit]` section, I get this message in the syslog everytime I invoke any `systemctl` command: `Unknown lvalue 'WantedBy' in section 'Unit', ignoring`. EDIT: And actually, the documentation link you posted shows it is supposed to go under `[Install]`.